# Install Ubuntu over Suse without affecting Windows

Tags: ubuntu, install, grub, windows, suse

I have Windows XP and Linux Suse 11 installed on my laptop for some time.

I want to replace my Suse installation with Ubuntu and would like to know if it is possible to do that without affecting the Windows installation.

I have the Grub boot-loader that came with Suse.

What are the steps to follow (I didn't do the initial installation so I don't know if it is safe or not)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy and low-risk. Just do the installation normally, and when the time comes to partition the disk, choose a manual partitioning strategy and make sure you override the Suse partition(s) only.

Ubuntu will want to override Suse's bootloader with its own. Let it: Grub needs some files in `/boot`, which you're going to overwrite. The Grub installer will automatically detect all installed operating system, so you'll still be able to boot both Linux and Windows. I don't know how Suse 11 configures Grub; the way to configure which OS gets booted by default might be different, so you should take a quick look at the [Ubuntu Grub community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).